# Where do I connect the HDD LED wires on my RAID adapter?

Tags: hard-drive, raid, led

I'm using a Promise FastTrak TX8660 with RAID 5. The manual (and Google) just doesn't seem to explain how exactly to connect a standard two-pin HDD LED wire to the eight available pins on the card.

The manual just says -
`To connect your LED, follow the following diagram:`

[image]

The card itself resembles the diagram:

[image]

But it doesn't make any sense to me. All I have is a two-pin connecter for HDD LED on the front of my computer case. I don't need anything fancy like the fault LED or seperate indicators for each drive. I just want to be able to see when my RAID 5 array is working, that's all. I don't know what the "R" and "G" stand for, but my HDD LED wires are red and white. I tried connecting the red wire to the "R" pin and the white wire to the "G" pin, but that just makes the LED on the front of my case light up indefinitely, even when the computer is idle.

Which pins am I suppose to connect the HDD LED header to for basic activity indication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hook it up between one of the `+` pins and the `-` pin next to it towards the center. The green pins are probably for power/presence/fault, so use the red pins instead. I'm not sure which of "global" or "aggregate" you should use, but if you don't like what it's showing then just choose the other pair.